# Select the first JSON array child value

Tags: arrays, json

I want to get the value that holds the first child of a JSON array.

This is the array :

```
var sms = {
    '1' : {
        'address' : '+123',
        'body' : 'SMS1'
    },
    '2' : {
        'address' : '+123',
        'body' : 'SMS2'
    },
    '3' : {
        'address' : '+123',
        'body' : 'SMS3'
    },
    '4' : {
        'address' : '+123',
        'body' : 'SMS4'
    }
};
```

The reason is i want to loop in it to search a string using the first childs
value as it is above. Example sms.[0] = 1;

Comment: That's not an array...

Comment: It's a JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the object using a using the `in` notation. Use `hasOwnProperty` to avoid getting references in the object

```
for (ii in sms) { 
  if (sms.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
    console.log(ii, sms[ii], sms[ii]['address'], sms[ii]['body']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the first child's value you can use

`sms['1']`

Which will return an object. If you want to access the values to the keys inside that object, you can use `sms['1']['address']` or `sms['1']['body']`.

The first `[]` accesses the child of the first layer of JSON, and the second `[<key_name>]` accesses the value of the second layer of JSON, containing keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I follow your instructions, but try this to access each element of this JSON.

```
for(i in sms){
console.log(sms[i]);    
}
```

Comment: This returns an object type not a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can JSON api to parse the JSON input and fetch the respective child

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringData);
JSONArray resultArr = obj.getJSONArray("sms");
JSONArray headrArr = null;
JSONObject jo = resultArr.optJSONObject(0);
if(jo != null){
    headrArr = jo.names();
}
System.out.println(headrArr.get(0));
```